# how can i make same background image on all pages in angular?

Tags: css, angular, background, background-image, styled-components

I can't make a background image for all my components, I made a style direct in html file of `app-component`, I tried on `app-component.css`  `html{}` and `body{}` but it didn't  work.

```html
<div
  class="container -5m"
  style="
    background-image: url(../../assets/background.jpg.crdownload);
    background-size: cover;
  "
>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/" class="btn btn-success">acceuil</a>
    <a routerLink="/register" class="btn btn-success">register</a>
    <a routerLink="/login" class="btn btn-success">login</a>
  </nav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I dont get it, what is the problem. I see in the right screenshot, an image.

Comment: There will be `styles.scss/css` file, there you can apply global styles. In that file you can modify `body`'s background image

Comment: i already made this  i  styles.css  body{
    background-image: url(./assets/background.jpg.crdownload);
    background-size: cover;   
}

Comment: but still not covering all the  page ,  should i  add something  ?? like  maxheight  or  maxwidht ??

Comment: Try to use the css from this link: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ to `style.css`